# I have this string : '123' and i want to split each number like that : "1,2,3"

Tags: python, split

I have this string : '123' and i want to split each number like that : "1,2,3".
I have tried this code, but it doesn't work :

```
str = '123'
str.split()
```

How do you know how do please ?

Thanks

Comment: @ExplooreX `split` will split on whitespace, not each character. It's not the right function.

Comment: Do you want to just format your string like `"1,2,3"`, or do you intend to do something with each individual number ? You said `split each number`.

Comment: It was 1,2,3, i got the good answer, thank you

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The simplest way is this:

```
','.join(str)
```

Answer (score 2):

split can't take an empty separator (raises `ValueError`), so you could do it with a list comprehension:

```
>>> [item for item in '123']
['1', '2', '3']
```